# Azure DevOps Query "Closed by" column is empty

Tags: azure-devops

When I do a query the column for `Closed by` is empty for an item in State `• Done`. I use Azure DevOps Server 2019.

What is causing this?

[image: Example]

Comment: Which process you are using? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=basic-process#workflow-states

Comment: We are using the Scrum template.

Comment: Okay i checked it on our AzureDevOps 2020 Instance, and wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour. If you can reproduce this, I would create a Issue https://aka.ms/azdo-support-submit/server-bug